# Вызов метода интерфейса

Tags: java, android, интерфейс

[image]
Есть интерфейс:

```
public interface BusinessRulesInterface {

    void select();

    void input(String UserName, String UID);

}
```

Методы этого интерфейса реализуются в другом класса, примерно так:

```
public class InterfaceRealization extends AppCompatActivity implements BusinessRulesInterface {
    
        @Override
        public void select() {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Нажата кнопка Select", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void input(String UserName, String UID) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Input: " + UserName +" " + UID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
```

Пробую обратиться к методам select() и input() этого интерфейса, из внешнего класса так:

```
public class BusinessRules {

    public void business_rules(int action, String UserName, String UID) {

        switch (action) {
            case (1):
                BusinessRulesInterface.select();
                break;
            case (2):
                BusinessRulesInterface.input(UserName, UID);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

но среда (Android Studio) не позволяет этого сделать.
Как обратиться к методам select() и input() интерфейса из внешнего класса?

Comment: А какого поведения вы ожидаете от методов интерфейса?

Comment: @Fleckinger
Методы этого интерфейса реализуются в другом классе, примерно так:

Comment: добавил в ответ вариант через анонимный класс

Answer (score 1):

```
BusinessRulesInterface.select();
```

это обращение через класс, следовательно надо сам метод делать статичным.

если надо просто вызвать метод как  `select();`

надо реализовывать следующим образом

```
public class BusinessRules implements BusinessRulesInterface
```

и в теле класса переопределять метод

```
 @Override
    public void select() {
    // что-то делаем
    }
```

если не переопределять, можно в самом интерфейсе сделать дефолтную реализацию

```
   default   void select(){
       // делать что-то
   }
```

через анонимный класс

```
new InterfaceRealization() {
            @Override
            public void select() {
            // делать -что-то
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, 
но хотелось бы сохранить независимость реализации методов (InterfaceRealization) от бизнес-правил (BusinessRules), которые должны только ссылаться на методы, определенные в интерфейсе (BusinessRulesInterface).
Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: @3asys заменить BusinessRulesInterface.select(); на new InterfaceRealization().select();

Comment: @3asys получилось?

Comment: Да, спасибо, получилось,
но задача немного сложнее, возможно:
BusinessRules и BusinessRulesInterface ничего не должны знать о InterfaceRealization,

Comment: Добавил в начало вопроса картинку для большей ясности.

Comment: так их связать тогда не получиться, в таком случае придётся в интерфейсе делать статичный метод с дефолтной реализацией

Comment: Собственно в этом и вопрос, можно ли обратиться извне к методу интерфейса, без статических методов? И если нет, то почему? (И как можно )) )

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131204/discussion-between--and-3asys).