# Вариант реализации чистой архитектуры Роберта Мартина

Tags: java

Требуется максимально простым способом реализовать такую архитектуру по мотивам книги Роберта Мартина:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В соответствии с данной архитектурой, Business Rules и Business Rules Interface ничего не должны знать про Interface Realization.
На данный момент показанные на рисунке модули выглядят так:
User Interface содержит вызов функции, находящейся в Bussiness Rules:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    BusinessRules businessRules = new BusinessRules();
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnSelect:
            businessRules.business_rules(1, null,null);
            break;
        case R.id.btnInput:
            businessRules.business_rules(2,etName.getText().toString(), etUID.getText().toString());
            break;
    }
}
```

Bussiness Rules содержит бизнес-логику (в зависимости от значения action, выполняем либо select(), либо input()):

```
public class BusinessRules {

    public void business_rules(int action, String UserName, String UID) {

        switch (action) {
            case (1):
                select();
                break;
            case (2):
                input(UserName, UID);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Business Rules Interface содержит интерфейс, определяющий select() и input():

```
public interface BusinessRulesInterface {

    void select();

    void input(String UserName, String UID);
}
```

Interface Realization содержит класс, имплементирующий функции интерфейса из Business Rules Interface:

```
public class InterfaceRealization extends AppCompatActivity implements BusinessRulesInterface {

    @Override
    public void select() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Нажата кнопка Select", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

    @Override
    public void input(String UserName, String UID) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Input: " + UserName +" " + UID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

Вопрос: **как правильно реализовать стрелочку из Business Rules к Business Rules Interface?**
P.S. Эта же тема затрагивалась мной в [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1346581/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0), но, возможно, там я неясно описал задачу, поэтому решил создать отдельный вопрос для более полного обсуждения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class BusinessRules {

  private BusinessRulesInterface businessRules;

  @Inject // - possibly
  public BusinessRules(BusinessRulesInterface businessRules) {
    this.businessRules = businessRules;
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как правильно задать содержимое параметров BusinessRules:  BusinessRules businessRules = new BusinessRules(???);

Comment: @3asys `new BusinessRules(new InterfaceRealization());` - или используйте Dependency Injection.

Comment: Большое спасибо @Igor !

Comment: @3asys Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа. Еще: относитесь критически к тому, что пишет и говорит Боб Мартин.

Comment: Подскажите, если не трудно @Igor , а как можно было бы использовать внедрение зависимостей, чтобы избежать ссылки из BusinessRules на InterfaceRealization (это лишает BusinessRules независимости от внешних компонентов) ?

Comment: @3asys Не понял. В `BusinessRules` нет зависимости от `InterfaceRealization`. `BusinessRules` знает только об интерфейсе `BusinessRulesInterface`.

Comment: Простите @Igor это опечатка, имел в виду, что выражение 
BusinessRules businessRules = new BusinessRules(new InterfaceRealization()) в классе UserInterface, приводит к зависимости UserInterface от InterfaceRealization

Comment: @3asys Это зависит от того, какой DI Framework Вы используете.

Comment: я бы хотел обойтись без фреймворков @Igor